# Import BibTex library in Libre Office Writer?

Tags: libreoffice, bibtex

Is it posible to import a BibTex library in Libre Office Writer?

I have a BibTex file that was generated with BibDesk and which I woul like to import in Libre Office.

Comment: For more elaborate answers, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/88163/working-with-bib-files-in-word-libreoffice

Answer (score 0):

Yes BibDesk can export to **.doc** (libre can import .doc) and many other formats. You can aslo modify the formats

> Ref [sourceforge SEC117](http://bibdesk.sourceforge.net/manual/BibDeskHelp_58.html#SEC117)
>
> Export Templates
>
> Templates allow you to export your database to a large variety of formats. It also allows you to **customize** to a great extent **how the data is exported**.
>
> To export using templates, choose the "Export..." menu item, which can be found under the "File" menu. You can choose the template from the "File Format" popup button. You can either export the whole database, or just the references which you have selected.
>
> BibDesk provides **several default templates**, for export to **HTML**, **RSS**, **Rich Text** **(RTF, RTFD)** and to **windows Doc format**.

You can also modify a template
[Bibdesk Templates](https://sourceforge.net/p/bibdesk/wiki/Templates/)

> You can find a set of default template files in the folder ~/Library/Application Support/Bibdesk/Templates. For HTML export, there are 3 template files: htmlExportTemplate.html, htmlItemExportTemplate.html and htmlExportStyleSheet.css. Generally, only the first of these template files is required
>
> Looking at the htmlExportTemplate.html file first, this is a relatively simple html document, with a standard header, a link to the external CSS file, and a single "content" div in the body. The formatting of the individual entries into the html file is done using the htmlItemExportTemplate.html file. Opening this file, you will see that the template files comprise a series of items enclosed in < and > signs, the same as those used in HTML to enclose formatting tags, but starting with an extra $. These entities are known as Template Tags.
>
> They are parsed by BibDesk to include the relevant parts of the BibDesk database in the html file. E.G.  will be replaced by the contents of the "Title" field in the BibDesk database. A list of the different kinds of Tag is given in the Export Template Keys page. It is also possible to apply modifiers to the field Tags in order to format the contents. One example is the  Tag where the full name or an abbreviated name can be chosen, and the "and"s between authors can be replaced by commas. These modifier keys are also explained at the Export Template Keys page.

I hope this helps